# Get slice of an Enumerator effectively

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I am having troubles getting a slice of an infinite sequence of `Enumerator` instance in a reasonable time. I first tried `drop` and `take` chain, but it hanged forever as `drop` tried to return an infinite `Array`. Next, I switched the order of these methods, but I still have to wait about ten minutes to get 100 values after ten-milionth sample:

```
print exbioseq.drop(10**7).take(100)
```

Can anything be done to get a slice faster?

Comment: ruby 2 will have lazy enumerators :) http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html. In the meanwhile, you can probably find something in 3rd-party gems

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Interesting. Still curious if it really does speed up things like my example. I quick-hacked the equivalent in python using itertools, islice method namely, and it has taken about 1/10th of time of ruby's run. AFAIK python is neither a lazy language.

Comment: Have you tried Haskell? It's a super-lazy language :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Enumerator` is very general interface, it makes only very simple assumptions about the "collection" it is traversing. In particular, it really only supports two operations: get the current element and iterate to the next element.

Given those two operations, if you want to get the 10 millionth element, there is only one thing you can do: iterate 10 million times. Which takes time.

There is no such thing as "slicing" an `Enumerator`. An `Enumerator` enumerates. That's it.

Now, as you discovered, there is *another* problem: Ruby's collection operations are not type-preserving. No matter what type of collection you call `map` or `select` or `take` or whatever on, it will always return the same type: a fully realized, concrete, strict `Array`. That's how most collection frameworks in most languages work, e.g. in .NET all collection operations return `IEnumerable`. That's because most of these methods have only a single common implementation in the `Enumerable` mixin.

Smalltalk is an exception, but there is another problem: the collection operations are duplicated for every single collection type. Every collection type has its own nearly-indetical practically copy&paste implementation of `collect:`, `select:` etc. This code duplication is hard to maintain and places a big burden on anyone who wants to integrate their *own* collection into the framework. In Ruby, it's easy: implement `each`, mixin `Enumerable` and you're done.

Note: as of Ruby 1.9, there is actually *some* of that duplication: `Hash` implements its own version of `select` which does actually return a `Hash` and not an `Array`. So, now, not only is there code duplication but also an asymmetry in the interface: all implementations of `select` return `Array`s except for the one in `Hash`.

The Scala 2.8 collection framework is the first time ever that someone has figured out how to provide type-preserving collection operations without code duplication. But Ruby's collection framework was designed 15 years before Scala 2.8, so it cannot take advantage of that knowledge.

In Ruby 2.0, there are lazy `Enumerator`s, where all collection operations return another lazy `Enumerator`. But that won't help you here: the only difference is that the lazy `Enumerator` will delay the 10 million iterations until you actually `print` the values. It still has to perform those 10 million iterations because there is simply no way to do otherwise.

If you want slicing, you need a sliceable data structure, such as an `Array`.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. As I mentioned in the comments rewriting the code in python using itertool, ie. using generator functions dropped the runtime to 1/10th. It looks like Enumerator class is not too optimised.

Comment: `Enumerator` is based on `Fiber`s, i.e. coroutines. That's 10 million context switches of what pretty much amounts to a lightweight thread. Python generators are not full coroutines, they are special cases. I'd imagine that the CPython implementors exploit that special case to make it more efficient than a general coroutine implementation.

Comment: `Fiber`s are only used when calling `Enumerator#next`, which is not the case here.