# Ruby Enumerator performance issue

Tags: ruby, performance, benchmarking

based on my previous related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978084/get-slice-of-an-enumerator-effectively), I've discovered huge performance gap when using `Enumerator` class to generate infinite sequences.
Before I did believed the hitch is with `Enumerable` methods `take` and `drop` but the following benchmark does not confirm this claim.

Example to create natural numbers generator and display numbers in interval (10e7-10, 10e7> :

```
require 'benchmark'

nats_range = (1..Float::INFINITY)
nats_enum = Enumerator.new {|y| i=1; loop { y << i; i+=1 }}

puts "#{'_'*79+"\n"}Benchmarking Enumerable methods on Range ..."
puts Benchmark.measure { print nats_range.take(10**7).drop(10**7-10), "\n" }

puts "#{'_'*79+"\n"}Benchmarking Enumerable methods on Enumerator ..."
puts Benchmark.measure { print nats_enum.take(10**7).drop(10**7-10), "\n" }


$ ruby a.rb 
_______________________________________________________________________________
Benchmarking Enumerable methods on Range ...
[9999991, 9999992, 9999993, 9999994, 9999995, 9999996, 9999997, 9999998, 9999999, 10000000]
  1.570000   0.010000   1.580000 (  1.576761)
_______________________________________________________________________________
Benchmarking Enumerable methods on Enumerator ...
[9999991, 9999992, 9999993, 9999994, 9999995, 9999996, 9999997, 9999998, 9999999, 10000000]
 15.620000   0.020000  15.640000 ( 15.665156)
```

The equivalent code using Enumerator is 10 times slower !

I'm asking here if anybody can explain this huge difference. Do I use the Enumerator improperly ? Is this a known regression in current Ruby implementation ?

MRI Ruby 1.9.3p385

Answer (score 3):

`Enumerator`s are based on `Fiber`s, which you can think of as very lightweight threads. (Actually, they are coroutines.)

`Range` uses `succ` for iteration and `<=` for figuring out whether it has reached the end yet.

So, your `Range` example uses 20 million method calls to `Fixnum#succ` and `Fixnum#<=`, both of which are heavily optimized and essentially map more or less directly to the correspondign assembly instructions.

Your `Enumerator` example uses 20 million calls to `Enumerator::Yielder#<<` (who knows how expensive that is) and `Fixnum#+` *as well as* 10 million `Fiber` context switches. I can easily imagine a `Fiber` context switch being 10 times more expensive than a simple `Fixnum` operation.

Comment: Mmmm, I believe `Fiber`s are only used when using `Enumerator#next`. The example given will only be using normal `yield`s.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune: How is `take` going to get the 10 millionth element if not by calling `next` 10 million times? There really is nothing in the `Enumerator` interface that would support a more efficient implementation or is there? And deliberately so: the whole point of such a broad and general interface is that *lots* of things can implement it.

Comment: It calls `each` and breaks when it gets to the 10 millionth element.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune: How does every iteration of `each` get the next element? Does it bypass `next`? Going off to read Rubinius source code now …

Comment: @JörgWMittag Also interested what you'll discover. By Ruby doc it looks like the MRI's `Enumerator#each` does not call the `next` method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are asking the right question.

If you need 10 elements and are generating and storing 10 billion, there is probably something wrong with your algorithm in the first place.

Moreover, there is no point in comparing an `Enumerator` with a `Range`, when the `Range` can't possibly give you the answer you seek.

It is fun to run microbenchmarks, but let's keep in mind that they are usually **meaningless**. Anyways, here's what I get with a more reasonable limit.

```
class AllNumbers
  include Enumerable
  def each
    i = 0
    loop { yield i += 1 }
  end
end

custom = AllNumbers.new
enum = Enumerator.new do |y|
  i=0
  loop { y << i+=1 }
end
range = 1..Float::INFINITY
require 'fruity'

limit = 1000
compare do
  using_range        {  range.take(limit) }
  using_enumerator   {   enum.take(limit) }
  using_custom_class { custom.take(limit) }
end
```

The results surprise me a bit:

```
using_custom_class is faster than using_range by 20.0% ± 10.0%
using_range is faster than using_enumerator by 70.0% ± 10.0%
```

I would not have guessed that. Indeed, `Range#each` is not optimized for integers, while `+=` is optimized.

Comment: First the example is only a demonstration. The original code using Enumerator is way too complex to put it in a question. Second I see I had rather to extend my class with Enumerable for tasks of generating infinite sequences. I'm really surprised it goes so well.